# How to rewrite the process name in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I would like to dynamically rewrite the process name in a NodeJS process.

In a past job, programming in the Ruby language, we simply rewrote the $0 variable like [the technique described in this article](https://varaneckas.com/blog/unicorn-procline/):

```
# rewriting the process name in Ruby

$0 = "my new process name"
```

But in NodeJS, the `Process.argv0` variable is a read-only cache of `$ARGV[0]`, so this NodeJS code does nothing.

```
Process.argv0 = "new process name"
```

Is there another way for a NodeJS process to rewrite its process name on a Unix operating system?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name by setting `process.title` - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/process.html#processtitle

This will pave any arguments, so if you want them to show up in the string, you may need to rebuild that from process.args.